# I want to access variables in a loop dynamically

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have a class called *DataGenerator.java* in which I have static String variables like `SoftwareQuestionnarie1` to `SoftwareQuestionnaire7`.

So, I want to use those values in another class. I don't want to write 7 statements, instead I want to use them in a loop like below. But, It didn't worked. I am thinking how could I do that. Is there any way?? Please help....

```
for(i=1;i<=7;i++)
{       
    PropertyMap.setProperties("SoftwareQuestionnarie"+i+".Selectors",DataGenerator.SoftwareQuestionnaire+Integer.toString(i));              

}
```

Comment: This is not possible using plain Java, You would require to use Reflections in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Java. We dont do it this way.

But

You could use a

```
 static String[] softwareQuestionnaire = new String[8];
```

To hold your data instead...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use HashMap for it. It will be dynamic array:

```
HashMap<String,Object> softwareQuestionaries = new HashMap<String,Object>();
for(i=1;i<=7;i++)
{
    softwareQuestionaries.put("SoftwareQuestionnarie"+i+".Selectors",
    DataGenerator.SoftwareQuestionnaire+Integer.toString(i));             
}
```